# How do beavers learn how to build dams?

Tags: zoology, ethology, learning

I was wondering whether all beavers, from all around the world, know how to build dams and lodges? Do they need to learn it from their parents? If you release a group of beavers in the wild that haven't been in contact with their parents, would they start to build stuff? or just hopelessly die/starve to death?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Question summary: *is dam building learned or instinctive in beavers?*

[A blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20200601171743/https://sites.google.com/site/sf11beavers/project-proposal/bibliography/annotated-bibliography/untitledpost) from 2011 references an article in the Juneau Empire titled *Running water is sound of spring for beavers*.  This article is no longer hosted on the Juneau Empire website, but [archived versions](https://web.archive.org/web/20120208025911/http://www.juneauempire.com/stories/050408/out_275269543.shtml) are available.

Here's an excerpt (emphasis mine) --

> Swedish biologist Lars Wilsson spent years studying captive and wild beavers, and he gained remarkable insights into their behavior. He raised beavers in an outdoor enclosure and in a large indoor terrarium ...
>
> Wilsson initially captured four adult beavers and later he raised a number of beavers from infancy, some in small colonies with their parents and **some completely isolated from adult beavers. He isolated the young beavers to see what beavers learn from their parents and what behaviors are instinctive.**
>
> **He found that young beavers - who had never even seen a beaver dam - were able to build almost-perfect dams at the first opportunity.**
>
> The foundation of sticks and logs anchored to the stream bottom, the interwoven lattice of trimmed branches, the mud chinking, every aspect of dam building was hard-wired. Beavers do get more skilled at dam building as they gain experience, **but the building behavior is instinctive**.
>
> Wilsson learned that the sound of running water is the cue for dam building and dam repair. In one experiment, he played a recording of running water, and the young beavers built a dam in a tank of still water in the terrarium. In another peculiar experiment, his captive beavers built a "dam" on a concrete floor against a loudspeaker that played the sound of running water.